# How to map element from one list to all elements in a sub-list to form a list of tuples (coordinates)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, element

I am trying to map each `element[x]` from list: rows to all elements of the `sub-list[x]` from another list: cols and the result should be a list of tuples. These 2 lists, rows and cols have the same length, each element in rows will correspond to a sub-list(of various length) in list cols.

The output should be a list of tuples in which each tuple will have the elements mapped/zipped :
`(row[0], cols[0][0]), (row[0], cols[0][1]), (row[1], cols[1][0])` and so on...

Input:

```
rows =  [502, 1064, 1500]
cols =  [[555, 905], [155, 475], [195, 595, 945]]
```

Desired Output:

```
mapped = [(502, 555), (502, 905), (1064, 155), (1064, 475), (1500, 195), (1500, 959), (1500, 945)]
```

thanks!

Comment: typo from your side in your desired output. last second map should be..! `(1500, 959)` -> `(1500, 595)`

Comment: true, and I like your solution too ! :)

Comment: glad to have been of help :) @mod13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
rows = [502, 1064, 1500]
cols = [[555, 905], [155, 475], [195, 595, 945]]

out = []
for r, c in zip(rows, cols):
    for v in c:
        out.append((r, v))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[(502, 555), (502, 905), (1064, 155), (1064, 475), (1500, 195), (1500, 595), (1500, 945)]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code: [List Comprehension]**

```
rows = [502, 1064, 1500]
cols = [[555, 905], [155, 475], [195, 595, 945]]

mapped = [(row, col) for row, nested_col in zip(rows, cols) for col in nested_col]

print(mapped)
```

**Output:**

```
[(502, 555), (502, 905), (1064, 155), (1064, 475), (1500, 195), (1500, 595), (1500, 945)]
```